# Circularly polarized electrons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, electrons, quantum-spin, polarization

Consider the reaction $e^+ e^- \to \mu^+ \mu^-$. Assume that the electron and the positron are linearly polarized, i.e. their spins are perpendicular to their momentum. So, they have to be polarized in the $x$- or $y$-direction when moving in the $z$-direction. This gives us the four initial states $$\left.|s_1s_2\right> = \left.|\updownarrow\updownarrow \right>, \left.|\leftrightarrow\leftrightarrow \right>,\left.|\updownarrow\leftrightarrow \right>, \left.|\leftrightarrow\updownarrow \right>,$$ where $s_1$ and $s_2$ denote the spins of the electron and the positron, respectively. Since the photon has spin 1, only the first two states can annihilate into a photon which then has the following polarization vectors: $$ \epsilon_1 = (0,1,0,0)\qquad\epsilon_2 = (0,0,1,0),$$ meaning that the photon is polarized in $x$-direction ($\epsilon_1$) or in $y$-direction ($\epsilon_2$).

My question is how to find the polarization vectors of the photon when we assume circular polarization. Can anybody show me how to do this?

Comment: The photon you are talkng about is virtual, no? off mass shell etc.. a real on mass shell photon has a spin +  or - to its direction of motion . see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light

Comment: @annav: Yes, the photon is virtual. How does this help me?

Comment: you need an answer by a theorist, but my impression is that in a virtual state polarization is not  a defining characteristic of a photon. spin, +/- is . afaik polarization is an emergent state out of superposition of the wavefunction of of real photons, as in the wiki link .